# Получить HTML-текст из HTMDocument и присвоить другому компоненту. Передача отформатированного текста между swing компонентами

Tags: java, html, swing

Добрый день.

К сожалению не смог найти решение самостоятельно, нужна помощь.

У меня есть HTMLDocument, который я получаю из JTextPane (text/html), содержащий всякий текст с различными формированиями. Мне нужно это текст, сохранив все его форматирования, присвоить другому компоненту, например JLabel. На первый взгляд задача выглядела просто - получить HTML, и присвоить его JLabel. Что-то типа такого:

```
 ....

    HTMLDocument myHTMLDoc= (HTMLDocument)editorPane.getStyledDocument();
....
private String getHTMLString(HTMLDocument doc){
    String HTMLString = null;
    HTMLEditorKit kit =  new HTMLEditorKit(); 
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        kit.write(writer, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
        HTMLString = writer.toString();
    } catch (IOException | BadLocationException e) {
        System.out.println("Error generate HTML-string!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return HTMLString;
}
....
   JLabel lbl = new JLabel(getHTMLString(myHTMLDoc));
```

Но результат получается не тот, что ожидался.
Если мой текст содержит форматирование, напр.,  "**Hello** World", я в строке с HTML-кодом получаю только неотформатированную часть - "World".

Т.е.

```
 myHTMLDoc.getText(0, myHTMLDoc.getLength()) ->  "Hello world"
```

Но, HTMLString ->

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      <!--
        Dialog-12-Bold { font-family: Dialog; font-size: 3; font-weight: bold; font-style: ; text-decoration: ; color: #333333 }
      -->
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      <font face="Dialog" size="3" color="#333333"><b><Dialog-12-Bold>
      </b></font> World
    </p>
  </body>
</html
```

Но куда пропадает мой отформатированный текст?

Я не пойму, что делаю не верно. То ли не верно формирую HTMLDocument, но он формируется средствами HTMLEditorkit из JtextPane.

Либо есть какой то другой, корректный способ получить HTML из HTMLDocument.

Или другой способ передать отформатированный текст между swing компонентами?

Answer (score 1):

Хм, у меня нашёлся более тривиальный способ;
Дело в том, что при загрузке текста в `JLabel` методом `setText` декодирование html-тегов происходит автоматически, если текст начинается с тега `<html>`. Тогда достаточно просто использовать конструкцию `<jLabel>.setText(<textPane>.getText());`. Я написал небольшой пример этого механизма для наглядности(+скрин, как док-во работоспособности):

```
package exp;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

/**
 * @author OldTeaOwl
 */
public class Tutorial {

    static ColorPane textPane = new ColorPane();
    static JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaviUtils.setNimbusLaF();
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tutorial");
        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu settings = new JMenu("Settings");
        JMenu exit = new JMenu("Exit");
        textPane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int red = rand.nextInt(255);
                int green = rand.nextInt(255);
                int blue = rand.nextInt(255);
                Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
                textPane.append(color, e.getKeyChar()+"");
                label.setText(textPane.getText());
            }
        });
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        menu.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 20);
        frame.setSize(400, 250);
        textPane.setBounds(5, 25, 370, 90);
        label.setBounds(5, 120, 370, 90);
        textPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        frame.add(textPane);
        frame.add(label);
        menu.add(settings);
        menu.add(exit);
        frame.add(menu);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ColorPane extends JTextPane {

    public void append(Color c, String s) {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY,
                StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
        int len = getDocument().getLength();
        setCaretPosition(len);
        setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        replaceSelection(s);
    }
}
```

[image: Скриншот результата тестирования]

Comment: Добрый день.Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: Так действительно работатет. Но предоставленный мной пример несколько упрощен. В действительности мне необходимо получить форматированный текст в компонент из ранее сериализованного HTMLDocument. И вот тут-то и возникла проблема.

Comment: @PaulScvortsov Попробуйте использовать метод по обработке HTMLDocument из кода вопроса, только присваивать лейблу текст не через конструктор, а через `setText()`, так вроде всё работает